# DataStax Enterprise Hive with PasswordAuthenticator and schema autocreation

Tags: authentication, hadoop, cassandra, hive, datastax

How can I configure Hive to connect to my Cassandra database using a username/password? Hive is configured to auto create schema and works well when Cassandra authentication is disabled. Of course, if I enable authentication, hive gives me an error message...

> FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient

Where can I specify the username/password? I cannot find anything in DataStax documentation about Hive... Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this docs page: [Configuring and using internal authentication](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/datastax_enterprise/4.5/datastax_enterprise/sec/secIntrnlAuth.html) and scroll down to the Hadoop section.

You should be able to provide the username/password as part of the `dse hive` command like this:

```
$ dse hive -hiveconf cassandra.username=foo -hiveconv cassandra.password=bar
```